# Converting data frame into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Below is my subsetted data frame, I am having a hard time trying to convert it into my desired output as I am fairly new to Python. Essentially I want to create a nested dictionary inside a list, with the column names as a value, and then another nested dictionary inside a list. Is this doable?

```
import pandas as pd

    Sector             Community Name
0   centre: 10901.0    park: 3238.0
1   northeast: 6958.0  heights: 1955.0
```

Desired output:

```
[{'column': 'Sector',
  'value': [{'name': 'centre', 'value': 10901.0},
   {'name': 'northeast', 'value': 6958.0}]},

  {'column': 'Community Name',
    'value': [{'name': 'park', 'value': 3238.0},
     {'name': 'heights', 'value': 1955.0},
     {'name': 'hill', 'value': 1454.0}]}]
```

Comment: what is the type of your pandas element?

Comment: if you meant just running .dtypes then it is dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@sushanth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63479961/14059614), I may add up to this solution. Assume that your dataframe variable is defined as `df`.

```
result = []
for header in list(df):
    column_values = df[header].to_list()
    result.append({
        "column" : header,
        "value" : [dict(zip(['name', 'value'], str(value).split(":"))) for value in column_values]
    })
```

Comment: that was perfect thank you so much, I guess just as a bonus. What if there are a lot values that are showing as ```{'name': 'nan}``` after using the function. Is there an easy way to remove those?

Comment: I am not sure about your cell values. But I think this [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` in above case might be a overkill, Here is a solution using python `inbuilt functions` which you can give a try,

```
input_ = {"Sector": ["centre: 10901.0", "northeast: 6958.0"],
          "Community Name": ["park: 3238.0", "heights: 1955.0"]}

result = []
for k, v in input_.items():
    result.append({
        "column" : k,
        "value" : [dict(zip(['name', 'value'], vv.split(":"))) for vv in v]
    })

print(result)
```

---

```
[{'column': 'Sector',
  'value': [{'name': 'centre', 'value': ' 10901.0'},
            {'name': 'northeast', 'value': ' 6958.0'}]},
 {'column': 'Community Name',
  'value': [{'name': 'park', 'value': ' 3238.0'},
            {'name': 'heights', 'value': ' 1955.0'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How could I make this work if my original data is in data frame format. while your input_ is already in a dictionary format?

Comment: What is the source for creating `dataframe` ?

Comment: it was just a sample dataframe but no worries someone else got the solution for me. Thank you for your time!